# XML to XSLT transformation - first time

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Playing around with xml and xslt, and trying to get the hang of it.

My xml code looks like this:

```
<hello-world>
    <header eng="Welcome!" dk="Velkommen"></header>
    <greeting>
        <eng>Hello, World!</eng>
        <dk>Hej verden</dk>
    </greeting>
    <greeting>
        <eng>Hello space</eng>
        <dk>Hej Rummet!</dk>
    </greeting>
    <greeting>
        <eng>Hey Mom! Im coding XSLT</eng>
        <dk>Hej Mor! Jeg koder XSLT</dk>
    </greeting>
</hello-world>
```

So far I've translated my xml to this html:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Hello, World!</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Hello space</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Hey Mom! Im coding XSLT</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Hej verden</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Hej Rummet!</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Hej Mor! Jeg koder XSLT</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

With the use of this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="/hello-world/greeting">
<div>
      <ul>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="eng" /></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="/hello-world/greeting">
<div>
      <ul>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="dk" /></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I would like to know, if there is a better way to do this, and how I could implement and select the correct attribute on the header and apply in the foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: In XSLT you can define your own *templates* using the [apply-template function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is somewhat the equivalent to a function in a procedural programming language.

Comment: Could you please re-edit your question so that the question will still be found by Google? At the moment the question is absoluetely useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In XSLT you can define your own templates using the [apply-template function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is somewhat the equivalent to a function in a procedural programming language. The template is applied to the selection value. Templates are a mighty concept. They can also accept parameters, so that you can pass more than one value to the template and control the flow.

You need to define the templates for the two languages (after the main template):

```
  <xsl:template match="dk">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="eng">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

and then *call them* in the main template for the wanted value:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="/hello-world/greeting">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="eng"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="/hello-world/greeting">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dk"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

The output will be the same as your original. You are basically saying something like `formatOutputFor(currentStringValue)`. The complete transformation looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="/hello-world/greeting">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="eng"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="/hello-world/greeting">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dk"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dk">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="eng">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Since both the templates are doing the same job, I think this code is little bulky and redundant.

Comment: It is just a variation of your solution. Yes, it contains redundant code, but i think it's easier to understand for a person, that is less experienced and familiar with the concept of XSLT.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what is wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template that does something for both "eng" and "dk" elements, and apply it in sequence for "eng" and "dk":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hello-world/greeting/eng"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hello-world/greeting/dk"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dk | eng">
     <div>
     <ul>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome, thats a great way! But still having a challenge applying the <header> in the sequence?

Comment: I'm sorry, but didn't understand the challenge. Could you please explain?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution :) Thanks for the help!